# Поиск файлов в директории по расширению C++

Tags: c++, файловая-система

Как сделать поиск файлов в деректории с определенным раcширением?

Comment: Если бы это был линукс, я бы выполнил команду `ls somedir/*.ext > filelist.txt` с помощью system, а потом спарсил файл filelist.txt. Ну это вот самое простое, без всяких там библиотек и прочего.

Comment: А за что минусы?

Comment: @isnullxbh, думаю, за то, что не указано направление расширения: вправо, влево, вперёд, назад или вверх.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, :)

Comment: @vegorov, для общего развития, почитай про `popen ()`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer  Я предложил самый простой вариант (из множества вариантов), не требующий от меня развёрнутого ответа и, надеюсь, понятный и полезный для ТС. Можно было просто добавить комментарий, что при желании зачитать вывод команды позволяет функция `popen()`, не обращаться на ты, не ставить многоточие, не делать предположений о моём "общем развитии". [Нормы поведения на этом сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct)

Comment: @vegorov, это был очень, _очень_, __очень__ плохой вариант... `popen ()` — это тот минимум, после которого перестаёшь желать страшной смерти тем кто так пишет... обычно в таких случаях получается просто пройти мимо, но в в этот раз как-то не вышло ;) ЗЫ: и да, в нормах поведения ничего из перечисленного нет...

Comment: @Fat-Zer `Никаких переходов на личности или личных выпадов. `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main() {
    const auto req_ext = ".a";
    for (const auto& filename : fs::directory_iterator("/usr/lib")) {
        if (!fs::path(filename).extension().compare(req_ext))
            std::cout << "file: " << filename << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Не забудьте указать `stdc++fs` в списке библиотек для линковки.

Вариант для CMake:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    stdc++fs)
```

**UPD.:** если Вам по какой-то причине нужны регулярные выражения, то см. код ниже (вариант для linux-based ОС).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    dirent* dirp;
    std::regex ext_regex("[a-z]+\\.a");
    if (DIR *dp = opendir("/usr/lib")) {
        while ((dirp = readdir(dp))) {
            if (std::regex_match(dirp->d_name, ext_regex)) {
                std::cout << dirp->d_name << "\n";
            }
        }
        closedir(dp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `stdc++fs` имеет катастрофический размер при статистической линковки, не рекомендую, очень тяжёлая вещь :) удобство от нее весьма обстрактное, при всем при этом, имхо конечно..

Comment: @NewView, спасибо за информацию! Я не знал об этом.